# How to assign a value to an EditorFor based on another editorFor value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

What if after the document is ready and user enters an input in an editorfor and i want to read that input and assign it to another editorFor after user has finished inputting it?

For example I have an editorFor called `basicSalary` and another editorFor `grossSalary`. So initially when user has finished entering a value into `basicSalary`, that value should be copied to `grossSalary`. My working is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#basicSalary").on('input',function(){
            $('#grossSalary').val($(this).val());
        });
```

Which is ofcourse incorrect since it applies only when the document is ready i.e., `$(document).ready(function ()` and user enters `basicSalary` afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> user enters an input in an editorfor and i want to read that input and assign it to another editorFor after user has finished inputting it?

Use `focusout` event as shown:-

```
$("#basicSalary").on('focusout',function(){
   $('#grossSalary').val($(this).val());
});
```

[**Reference**](https://api.jquery.com/focusout/)

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/5594/)

Comment: Sorry. `focusout` isn't doing whats desired.

Comment: @RehanKhan...`focusout` should work ... what exactly do you want?

Comment: I want `basicSalary` value to be copied to `grossSalary` field. When the form laods, both the fields are empty. User enters a value into `basicSalary`. I need this value to be copied to `grossSalary` when user has finished entering it. Thanks

Comment: @RehanKhan..the code shown above will do this for you..as soon as `#basicSalary` will loose focus it's value will copied to `#grossSalary`.

Comment: I exactly copy pasted your code into the solution but for some reason its not doing it.

Comment: @RehanKhan..make sure you have included jquery js file in your page.

Comment: Yes. That was the reason. After I added `jquery-2.1.4.js`, it has started working. Thanks alot for all your help. I've marked your answer as correct. Cheers.

Comment: @RehanKhan..happy to help you..;)